# \Drupal::currentUser() returns information about the anonymous user, even though I am logged in

Tags: users, 8

I'am trying to check whether a user is logged-in or not; with `\Drupal::currentUser()->id()` I am getting the user ID for the anonymous user (i.e. 0), even though I'm logged in.

How can I resolve this?

I'm just calling this function in the `.module` file, and it is not run from cron. I am using the following code.

```
use Drupal\Core\Session\UserSession;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;

$user = \Drupal::currentUser();
if ($user->isAuthenticated()) {
  echo 'logged-in';
}
else {
  echo 'guest';
}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems like an odd issue, I'm wondering if showing some code would help figure out what's going on.

Comment: What is the context in which you are calling the currentUser method? Is it inside of a hook? If so, what hook?

Comment: Please show the function containing that code, or we are just going to guess.

Comment: Which function you put the code?

Answer (score 3):

To determine if a user is logged-in (authenticated), it would be best to use:

`\Drupal::currentUser()->isAuthenticated()`

Comment: the `\Drupal::currentUser()` is returning the anonymous user object, therefore, `isAuthenticated()` function returns false.Well the main thing is why `\Drupal::currentUser()` is returning anonymous user when i'm logged-in as admin.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are running your code directly from your `.module` file and not inside a function. This way your code may not work because most services are likely to be not instantiated at the time the module files are included.

Try to run your code from a hook (e.g. [hook_entity_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_view/8.2.x)) or use [Devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel)'s *Execute PHP-Code* functionality (at */devel/php*).

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;

function mymodule_function() {
  $account = \Drupal::currentUser();
  if ($account->isAuthenticated()) {
    // User is logged in.
  }
}
```

Refer the below Link for more details

https://www.drupal.org/node/2017231

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this kind of behaviour when using hook_download_file. However in my situation I had varnish to pass request to Drupal backend and I were downloading file through Drupal. Varnish checked that it's actually file and stripped out cookies that contains session info.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
\Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id())->uid->value
```

Comment: it isn't working either. It displays The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Comment: @user1960 where do you test this? in module, in preprocess hook? where?

Comment: in .module file and in module controller class.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of more robust and descriptive code, you can make use of the handy User::isAnonymous() method, e.g.

```
if (\Drupal::currentUser()->isAnonymous()) {
  // Anonymous user...
}
```

or

```
$user = \Drupal::currentUser();

if ($user->id() == 0) {
    // is visitor
}
else {
    // is logged
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the code in the original post is not in any function, it's just in the global spec of whichever file it's in, so the current user probably hasn't been loaded yet.

Comment: The [OP commented saying](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/205593/drupalcurrentuser-returns-information-about-the-anonymous-user-even-though#comment250139_205596): in .module file and in module controller class.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue in some code today. The code was in a controller and the controller was mapped to a route for a URL which was being accessed by users from emails.

The problem was that the URLs in the emails had http and the site was running on https. The site was also accessible via http and was not automatically redirecting to https.

So when the user comes to the site from the email he would be on http and the session would be an anonymous session.

Hope this helps somebody!